# How to add new objects to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have to write a function that will create an array filled with the indicated number of objects that represent three "types" of these objects.

WITHOUT using for or while loop and not doing that manually?
I don't know how can I add these objects into the array.

I'm choosing the type of object by random, but how can I add them to the array?

these are the objects:

```
 var bestaccount=function(){
   var amount=0;
   this.pay=function(howmuch){amount+=howmuch;};
   this.widthdraw=function(howmuch){amount-=howmuch;};
   this.saldo=function(){return amount;};
   };

   var toGive= function(){
   var amount=0;
   this.pay=function(howmuch){amount+=howmuch;};
   this.saldo=function(){return amount;};
   };

   var toWithdraw=function(){
   var amount=0;
   this.withdraw=function(howmuch){amount-=howmuch;};
   this.saldo=function(){return amount;};
   };
```

For example there are 3 toWithdraw objects, 1 bestAccount and 1 toGive. I want them all in one array.

EDIT:
Sorry, I was using completely wrong functions.

If anyone needs it, I'm doing it with apply(). 
Here's the code:

```
 function fillArrayWithNumbers(n) {

        arr = Array.apply(null, Array(n));
        tabl= arr.map(function (x, i) { return new objects[Math.floor(Math.random()*objects.length)](); });
      return tabl;
    }
```

Sorry, but no stress guys. Everyone started somehow.

Comment: forEach works with an Array, so if you have 4 objects that you want to iterate over...you could put them in an Array and use forEach. `[object1, object2, object3, objec54].forEach` ... but without more of an example, it's unclear what you're looking for.

Comment: you need to read more tutorials in javascript loops

Comment: Why do you _have_ to do it with `forEach` instead of a simple `for` loop?

Comment: This question is ridiculously broad.

Comment: Without using `for` loops? Specific number of `object`s? `var p=7; new Array(p).fill({});` Is this what you want? If not, **clarify your question**.

Comment: This question has only changed 5 times in 13 minutes. When _you_ realize what you're looking for, let the rest of us know. otherwise, stop editing it every 30 seconds hoping we'll take back the down-votes.

Comment: It gets more and more confusing: _“the three types of these objects”_ —every object in JS has only one type.

Comment: **Hint:** clarify your question by adding an ***expected*** **result** and an example of your program flow (i. e. ***example*** **input**, ***example*** **output**).

Comment: It is a homework indeed, but I only need some advice with the arrays, I don't think i'ts something bad. I thought it was easy to understand, I was wrong sorry, I guess it's all I want to say now above.

Comment: To your latest edit: you are answering yourself in your question. Please post a separate **answer** with your solution. Also, I can’t run this code because `objects` is undefined. Ergo, your code is incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

**Now that you have answered your own question, I see that I have misinterpreted it. Anyway, here is how to add objects to an array:**

You can add new elements to an array with push like this:

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.push("Kiwi");
```

Now, instead of an array with strings, you want an array with objects. So you can first create the object like this:

```
var myObject = {numberOfGive: 1, numberOfWithdraw: 3, numberOfBestAccount: 1};
```

And then push it to your array:

```
var myArray = [];
myArray.push(myObject);
```

[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)

Comment: w3schools is [not a great reference](http://w3fools.com). I would recommend using [MDN](http://developers.mozilla.org/).

Comment: @BradChristie While I agree, this is personal preference nonetheless.

Comment: Here is the [MDN source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push). Put I do agree, will start to use MDN as source from now on

Comment: The W3Fools like says that W3Schools offers a decent learning experience for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

here's my solution:

```
var objects =[bestaccount,toGive,toWithdraw];

function fillArrayWithNumbers(n) {

        arr = Array.apply(null, Array(n));
        tabl= arr.map(function (x, i) { return new objects[Math.floor(Math.random()*objects.length)](); });
      return tabl;
    }
```

Thanks for response.